# VBA fill multi-line PDF?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I'm trying to use the adobe acrobat 9.0 API with VBA to fill a form field (text) with multiple lines. However when i try to fill the form field with a single string seperated by carriage returns (CHR13) it only shows the first line. I have the multi-line option selected in the PDF and i can confirm it is at least trying to input the multiple lines when i test it. I'm not sure what i'm doing incorrectly here, is this not possible?

I am using adobe acrobat 9.0 and vba code through excel using PDDoc to code this.

I can post some code if need be, i just want to generically know if theres a way to do this.

Comment: Some code would definitely be helpful. Please post.

Comment: What happens when you use "\n" or "\r" instead of CHR13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat wants a line feed, not a carriage return. Use "\n" instead.